# Wordpress: specify an upload folder for a custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, plugins, avatar

I use the [Simple Local Avatars plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-local-avatars/) to allow users to add a forum picture on my Wordpress website.

The default upload path is www.site.com/wp-content/uploads. Yet as I will have 100-1000 users and as this plugins creates 5 files for each avatar, it will completely mess the upload folder.

I would like that the pictures to be uploaded in www.site.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/ instead.

This plugin seems to get path trough:

```
$upload_path = wp_upload_dir();
```

I tried several hacks such as:

```
 $upload_path = wp_upload_dir();
 $upload_path['baseurl'] .= '/avatars';
 $upload_path['basedir'] .= '/avatars';
```

Which rises major bug as it (i don't why) include the picture binary values in the path ...

Or this [solution](http://yoast.com/smarter-upload-handling-wp-plugins/):

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');
$upload = wp_upload_dir();
remove_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');

funcion my_upload_dir($upload) {
    $upload['subdir']   = '/sub-dir-to-use' . $upload['subdir'];
    $upload['path']     = $upload['basedir'] . $upload['subdir'];
    $upload['url']      = $upload['baseurl'] . $upload['subdir'];
    return $upload;
}
```

Which does not affect the actual upload folder.

Also the plugin author does not seem to want to add this feature see [this support topic](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-directory-to-store-avatars).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little bit late, but you have to provide the absolute paths for `path` and `basepath`.